# Kdenlive flatpak installation issue

Tags: software-installation, kdenlive, flatpak

Kdenlive's website [has instructions for installing their Flatpak here](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.kde.kdenlive). The command I used is

`flatpak --user install flathub org.kde.kdenlive`

which give this error on Ubuntu 18.04

`error: Remote "flathub" not found`

I have installed Flatpak previously and don't know what went wrong. Do you?

Comment: Have you followed all the steps here (https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/) to enable flatpacks (and the flathub repository)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm just giving up on Flatpak. Too many issues no matter the program I try. `Snaps` or `apt-get` it is for me.

Answer (score 1):

Visited the link you provided... You're not following their directions exactly...

To install:

```
flatpak install flathub org.kde.kdenlive
```

To run:

```
flatpak run org.kde.kdenlive
```

I installed flatpak a few days ago, using `sudo apt-get install flatpak` with no issues. I have also installed and executed a couple of flatpak app packages... If all else fails `flatpak --help`.

Comment: Thanks but I need to use the `--user` option. So this won't get me there.

Comment: Looking at flatpaks help right now. There is no "--user" flag described...

Comment: http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/using-flatpak.html

Comment: Just installed org.kde.kdenlive via what I posted above... You do realize that flatpak apps aren't installed in the same fashion as a normal Linux app would be? flatpak is used for installing, executing, and removing flatpak apps.

Comment: Ok. This is a flatpak issue. I just removed org.kde.kdenlive and tried installing using the --user switch. IT DOES NOT work. Also the "--user" switch doesn't show in "flatpak --help" but is described in the link you posted... I've done what I can, sorry.